# Strange behaviour with MySQL 5.5.14 TO_DAYS partitioning schema

Tags: mysql

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp;
CREATE TABLE `temp` (
`CallID` bigint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
`InfoID` bigint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
`CallStartTime` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
PARTITION BY RANGE (TO_DAYS(CallStartTime))
(
PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2013-06-01 00:00:00' )),
PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2013-07-01 00:00:00')), 
PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2013-08-01 00:00:00')), 
PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2013-09-02 00:00:00'))) ;
```

I use EXPLAIN in a sample query I get the next result:

```
EXPLAIN PARTITIONS SELECT * FROM temp where CallStartTime >= '2013-07-13 00:10:06' AND  CallStartTime <= '2013-07-22 10:24:00'
```

---

id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra

1   SIMPLE  temp    p0,p2   ALL                 3   Using where

I don't know why it's using the p0 partition where it's not between the date specified in the BETWEEN statement.

Comment: [This bug report](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=49754) seems relevant.

Answer (score 1):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-range.html
says at the bottom of the page:

2.Partition the table by RANGE COLUMNS, using a DATE or DATETIME column as the partitioning column. For example, the members table could be defined using the joined column directly, as shown here: 
........

So for your example it would look like this:
PARTITION BY RANGE COLUMNS(CallStartTime) (
    PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN ('2013-06-01 00:00:00' ),
....

Even I do not understand from the first glance why your example does not work, but it looks like there are still some bugs in partitioning.

Bernd

Comment: ALTER TABLE temp PARTITION BY RANGE (CallStartTime)
(
PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN ('2013-06-01 00:00:00' ),
 PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN ('2013-07-01 00:00:00'), 
 PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN ('2013-08-01 00:00:00'), 
 PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN ('2013-09-02 00:00:00')) ;   
 when i execute MySQL Database Error: VALUES value for partition 'p0' must have type INT

Comment: The use of partitioning columns employing date or time types other than DATE or DATETIME is not supported with RANGE COLUMNS.

Answer (score 0):

The use of partitioning columns employing date or time types other than DATE or DATETIME is not supported with RANGE COLUMNS.

DATE and DATETIME.
Columns using other data types relating to dates or times are not supported as partitioning columns.